# Using IBAction Instead of touchesBegan:

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitouch, touchesbegan

Is there any real difference between setting an IBAction to handle your touch event vs. using touchesBegan: touchesMoved, etc?  What considerations would cause one to be preferred over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Accessibility

If by `IBAction` you mean attaching to events like `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`, there is quite a bit of "magic" attached to control events that would take some work to duplicate touch events.

Most obviously, if you touch a `UIButton`, then drag a *short* distance off the button before releasing, the button still sends its `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` event.  The distance was chosen through usability experiments: how far can someone's finger slip while they still think they're pressing the button?

I suspect that using control events will also make it easier for [iOS 6 Guided Access](http://www.apple.com/ios/ios6/#accessibility) and other accessibility aids to understand your app.

### Separating the View from the Model

Using control events means that the View doesn't need to know what effect it has when tapped.  This is considered a good thing in the Model-View-Controller paradigm.  Ideally your Controller will receive the event, and update the Model to suit.

### Conclusion

If you *can* implement your interaction with control events, it's better to do so.

Sometimes your control needs complex interaction, though.  If you're implementing something like finger painting with multi-touch, you're going to need to know *exactly* where and when touches happen.  In that case, implement your interaction with `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, `touchesEnded` and `touchesCancelled`.

Comment: Awesome answer.  Thanks for the illumination.